# Correct tense with ever

Tags: grammar

Please help me choose the correct verb tense with ever:

> William Shakespeare is the best playwright  who **ever lived/has ever
>   lived.**
>
> William Shakespeare was the best playwright who **ever lived/has ever
>   lived.**
>
> William Shakespeare is one of the best playwrights who **have ever
>   lived/ever lived**.

Answer (score 2):

The following are the normal expressions:

> - William Shakespeare is the best playwright who ever lived.
> - William Shakespeare was the best playwright who ever lived.
> - William Shakespeare is one of the best playwrights who ever lived.

The following are more awkward and uncommon but probably grammatically correct:

> - William Shakespeare was the best playwright who has ever lived.
> - William Shakespeare is the best playwright who has ever lived.
> - William Shakespeare is one of the best playwrights who has ever lived.